# Flash video streaming in iOS

Tags: ios, flash, ffmpeg, browser, video-streaming

i am trying to make a web browser app for iOS. upto now i am able to to browse desktop version of websites in it and play iOS competible videos also. But i want to have support for flash videos alos. my inspiration is [vBrowse](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vbrowse-flash-video-desktop/id418791028?mt=8) and according to there [statement](http://bewhere.co.uk/vBrowse/about.html) they are using "FFmpeg" and "librtmp" in their app. so can anyone help me to implement this library so that my browser would support swf/flv videos.

Bundle thanx in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are writing a native app, then that is possible.

You can use ffmpeg-1.0 and just compile it with out lib rtmp support, as ffmpeg has already this library in it. After that

1. connect to server - avformat_open_input
2. find & open codecs - avcodec_open2
3. read packets - av_read_frame
4. if pkt is audio, decode it (avcodec_decode_audio4) and play it with audioqueue or audiounit
   if pkt is video  decode it (avcodec_decode_video2) and convert it to RGB and scale it and show it on the screen

at glance you should do above... Also, you can have a look our paid sdk located in http://www.videostreamsdk.com it supports streaming from rtmp servers